# How to generate json streamformat java object in FileSource of Flink 1.18.1

Tags: json, apache-flink, flink-streaming

According to the [Flink 1.18.1 documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/json/), I can find the following codes to handle the json type data.

```
JsonDeserializationSchema<SomePojo> jsonFormat=new JsonDeserializationSchema<>(SomePojo.class);
KafkaSource<SomePojo> source=
    KafkaSource.<SomePojo>builder()
        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(jsonFormat)
        ...
```

Then I try to make codes to handle json type data in local file.

```
JsonDeserializationSchema<SomePojo> jsonFormat = new JsonDeserializationSchema<>(SomePojo.class);
FileSource<SomePojo> source_json = FileSource
            .forRecordStreamFormat(jsonFormat, new Path(".\\data", "sample.json"))
            .build();
DataStream<SomePojo> ds_json = env.fromSource(source_json, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "file-json");
ds_json.print();
```

But `FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat` function throws Exception. The Exception is like below,

```
The method forRecordStreamFormat(StreamFormat<T>, Path...) in the type FileSource is not applicable for the arguments (JsonDeserializationSchema<T>, Path)Java(67108979)
<T> FileSourceBuilder<T> org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(StreamFormat<T> streamFormat, Path... paths)
```

The parameter type of `JsonDeserializationSchema` is incorrect, but the type is `StreamFormat`. But I have no idea how to generate the json type `StreamFormat`. Kindly inform me how to generate json type `StreamFormat` object in Flink 1.18.1. Any referenece site or some codes will be grateful. Thanks.